# Cache static content for asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, browser-cache

I am trying to configure caching static page elements (images, scripts, styles).
file web.config.

```
<clientCache cacheControlCustom="public;max-age"
             cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00"
             cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
```

Controller

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

[image]

What is the reason why there is no cached content?

Comment: Don't you happen to have "Disable cache" enabled? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/60188

Comment: in a browser is, Disable cache